# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'kill'

Tags: python, jython

Here is my code:

```
def cmdoutput(cmd1, flag):
    finish = time.time() + 50
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(1)
        if finish < time.time():
            os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            print "timed out and killed child, collecting what output exists so far"
        if (flag == "1"):#To enable container
            out, err = p.communicate(input='container\nzone1')
    else:
        out, err = p.communicate()
    print (out)
    return out
```

When I run this script, I get

```
Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'kill'.
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you running a standard installation of python?  If so, check if you have the right `os` module - you may have accidentally modified it or imported your own.

Comment: I am using Jython 2.7.1 and instead of os.kill(..) I am using p.kill() but it is throwing "NameError: global name '_subprocess' is not defined". now sure what is the problem. appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your own `os.py`.

Put `print os.__file__` before `os.kill(...)` line, and you will see what's going on.

---

**UPDATE**

[os.kill is only available in unix in jython](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/os.html)

Instead of `os.kill(...)`, use `p.kill()`.

**UPDATE**

`p.kill()` not work. (At least in Windows + Jython 2.5.2, 2.5.3).

`p.pid` is None.

http://bugs.jython.org/issue1898

Comment: I am using Jython in fact. and I am running it on windows 2008 server.

Comment: how should I print them, shall I simply put "print os.__file__" before kill. what is the file here

Comment: it says "Unable to retrieve variable "file""

Comment: "<module 'os' from '.\3rdparty\jython\Lib\os$py.class'>" -- that is what it printed

Comment: I replaced os.kill(...) with p.kill() and now its showing as "AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'kill'"

Comment: I tried print (p.pid) before the kill and it showed "None". not sure why is it showing as None rather than the process id.

Comment: I am running on Jython 2.5.2

Comment: I have to use Jython here. is there any other way to kill that process. Please help.

Comment: I am now using Jython 2.7.1

Comment: I am using p.kill() but it is throwing an error as "NameError: global name '_subprocess' is not defined". this is on Jython 2.7.1

Comment: I am just trying to check if my Jython script works in any of the released Jython versions. We are actually calling this Jython script from another source so we have limited options. I have Python too installed on the server but we can not use that. I dont know why this Jython is giving so much of issues.

Comment: this is an api level automation what we are trying do here so we are using a tool called API Tester Tool and using this tool we are trying to call Jython Script which does calls CLI commands

Comment: yes, that fine. but for that do I need to include CPython Libs

Comment: ok.. my email id is rahulnanjundegowda@gmail.com you can send an email to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the wrapper** `from pyngrok import ngrok`.

Below I am sharing my own working example which tunnels `MLFlow` from `GoogleColab` to a temporary public server on `ngrok`.

```
from pyngrok import ngrok
import mlflow
from getpass import getpass
import logging

# prepare logging
logger = logging.getLogger('My Analysis')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Run mlflow server
get_ipython().system_raw("mlflow ui --port 5000 &")

# Terminate open tunnels if exist
ngrok.kill()

# Setting the authtoken (optional)
# Get your authtoken from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth
NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN = getpass('Enter the ngrok authtoken: ')  
ngrok.set_auth_token(NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN)

# Open an HTTPS tunnel on port 5000 for http://localhost:5000
ngrok_tunnel = ngrok.connect(addr="5000", proto="http", bind_tls=True)

# visit the tracking address to enable it
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(ngrok_tunnel.public_url)
logger.info(f"MLflow Tracking UI:{ngrok_tunnel.public_url}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow. Change `CPYTHON_EXECUTABLE_PATH`, `CMDOUTPUT_SCRIPT_PATH`.

```
CPYTHON_EXECUTABLE_PATH = r'c:\python27\python.exe' # Change path to python.exe
CMDOUTPUT_SCRIPT_PATH = r'c:\users\falsetru\cmdoutput.py' # Change path to the script

def cmdoutput(cmd1, flag):
    return subprocess.check_output([CPYTHON_EXECUTABLE_PATH, CMDOUTPUT_SCRIPT_PATH, flag])
```

Save following code as `cmdoutput.py`

```
import subprocess
import sys

def cmdoutput(cmd1, flag):
    finish = time.time() + 50
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(1)
        if finish < time.time():
            p.kill()
            return '<<timeout>>'
        if flag == "1":
            out, err = p.communicate('container\nzone1')
    else:
        out, err = p.communicate()
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd, flag = sys.argv[1:3]
    print(cmdoutput(cmd, flag))
```

Comment: I actually removed the PIPE in the process and it worked (p.returncode). do you know how to capture the output of the command without having PIPE?

Comment: @user2511126, Without PIPE, you cannot get output as far as I know.

Comment: I am not using p.communicate() here. Although I am using PIPE only for STDOUT as to fetch the result, I am more dependent on p.returncode which confirms me if the command is success / failure, later I will use stdout.readline() to fetch the result.

Comment: Please update your code in question. Without code, it's hard to know what you mean.